# RPC is block while used in unit test

Tags: unit-testing, grpc-java

I want to test wheter gRPC works, so i start the server in junit test with a thread(see setUp in below code). Everything is ok in non-unit test.

But when I use client to connect the server, it blocks.

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws InterruptedException {
    rpcSever = new RPCServerImpl();
    new Thread(rpcSever).start();
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10);
    rpcClient = new RPCClient("localhost", 50051);
}

//@Test
public void testPing() throws InterruptedException {
    assertTrue(rpcClient.ping());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reference https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/master/examples/src/test/java/io/grpc/examples/helloworld for how to test grpc.